# ServiceStack Razor MinifyHtml

Tags: servicestack

Use the RazorFormat plugin in .netframework, which has a MinifyHtml property. Why does not the .netcore use this plug-in without the MinifyHtml property?

in .netframework

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat{MinifyHtml = true, UseAdvancedCompression = true});
```

in .netcore

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
```

How to implement MinifyHtml in .net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ServiceStack.Razor implementation in .NET Core uses MVC Razor](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-razor#mvc-razor-pages) which handles all compilation and rendering of Razor Views which means ServiceStack does not control the Razor output in .NET Core and can't offer the [HTML, CSS and JavaScript Minification](http://docs.servicestack.net/html-css-and-javascript-minification) functionality like it can on the .NET Framework.